# Help understanding the solution to #83 Section 9.1 Calculus 9e, by Larson.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find $a_n$ of  $1, \; \frac{-1}{1\times 3}, \; \frac{1}{1\times3\times5}, \frac{-1}{1\times 3\times 5 \times 7}$

I solved it as $\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)!}$

The solution guide says: $\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2^n n!}{\left(2n\right)!} $

I am unable to figure out how $2^n$ gets into the numerator.

if you multiply $\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)!}$ by $\dfrac{2n}{2n}$ results in $\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2n}{\left(2n\right)!}$

Please, help me understand how $2n$ goes to $2^n n!$

**Have learned from the comments that the denomator is $\left(2n-1\right)!!$**  Sorry, still not sure how to solve this problem.  This is my first time learning calculus and haven't seen any double factorials.  Hate this about this Larson Calculus book, great problems, but they are like Sherlock Novels, always some missing knowledge not showen that is needed to solve the later problems.

Comment: Take a another look at the factorial expression you have in the denominator. It doesn't equal what you think it equals.

Comment: (2(2)-1)!=5!= 1*2*3*4*5 and not 1*3*5

Comment: @RichardSullivan How am I to know that! This is my first time learning calculus.  Could you explain what $\left(2n-1\right)!!$ equals?

Comment: I've not personally seem that notation. The claimed solution is correct, but not equivalent to yours, so trying to show equivalence will hold you back. Do you know induction?

Comment: @MaoYiyi The $!!$ notation is new to me too. But you should still be able to see that $(2n-1)!$ does not "skip" even integers in the product. (See Amr's comment above, for example.)

Comment: @RichardSullivan Yes, I see that know, got tunnel vision on this problem.

Comment: @MaoYiyi http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial

Comment: @Richard Sullivan's first comment is merely pointing out that $\frac{2n}{2n} \neq \frac{2^n}{2n}$.

Comment: @gnometorule I know, that is what was confusing me and I got tunnel vision on the problem and did know about double factorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $(2n-1)!!$, not $(2n-1)!$. Use that $(2n)!!=2^n n!$

If you don't know: $(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots \cdot3 \cdot 1$ and $(2n)!!=(2n)(2n-2)\cdot \ldots 4 \cdot 2$

**Hint:** multiple and divide by $(2n)!!$, note that $(2n-1)!! \cdot (2n)!!= (2n)!$

Full solution:

> $\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)!!}=\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)!!} \cdot \dfrac{(2n)!!}{(2n)!!} = \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}(2n)!!}{\left(2n-1\right)!!(2n)!!}=\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2^n n!}{\left(2n-1\right)!!(2n)!!}=\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2^n n!}{(2n)!}$

Proof that $(2n)!!=2^n n!$:

> \begin{align*}(2n)!!&=(2n)(2n-2)\cdot \ldots \cdot 4 \cdot 2\\ &= (2n)(2(n-1))\cdot \ldots \cdot (2\cdot 2) \cdot (2\cdot 1)\\
> &=2^n (n(n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1) = 2^n n!\end{align*}

Proof that $(2n-1)!! \cdot (2n)!!=(2n)!$:

> $\underbrace{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots \cdot3 \cdot 1}_{(2n-1)!!}\cdot \underbrace{ (2n)(2n-2)\cdot \ldots 4 \cdot 2}_{(2n)!!}= (2n)(2n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1=(2n)!$

Comment: So, how do you compute $\left(2n-1\right)!!$

Comment: @MaoYiyi I edited. Easier now?

Comment: You know of another solution method that doesn't involve double factorials? Upset with Larson right now, for this not covered knowledge needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Given the multitude of asymptotic constants havin $(.)!!$ or $(.)! \dots !$, I have a hard time seeing this as standard notation. I am curious: would you have a reference/name for it?

Comment: Great answer, uhm Could you help me figure out how $2^n n! = \left(2n\right)!!$

Comment: @MaoYiyi I just edited.

Comment: @gnometorule en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial

Answer (score 3):

In the denominator, we note that there's a product of odd numbers and at the numerator there's an alternate sign $\pm$  then $a_n$ must be on the form $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{1\times 3\times \cdots\times (2n-1)}$.

Now, let's multiply both numerator and denominator by $2\times 4\times \cdots\times (2n)$

$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{1\times 3\times \cdots\times (2n-1)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2\times 4\times \cdots\times (2n)}{1\times2\times3\times 4\times \cdots\times(2n-1)\times (2n)}\\=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2\times 1)\times( 2\times 2)\times\cdots\times(2\times n)}{(2n)!}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^nn!}{(2n)!}.$$

Comment: The $2\times 4\times \ldots \left(2n\right) = \left(2n\right)!!$ and you just reversed the order?

Answer (score 1):

No different results here but a somewhat different way of working through it.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{n}&1& 2 &3& 4 & 5\\
\hline
a_n&1&\frac{-1}{1\cdot3}&\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}&\frac{-1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}&\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}\\
\end{array}

Terms like $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ are similar to factorials, except they are
missing the even numbers. But notice that $2^2 \cdot2!$ = $2\cdot4$, that $2^3 \cdot3! = 2\cdot4\cdot6$, that $2^4\cdot4! = 2\cdot 4\cdot6\cdot8$, and so on. So for example $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot 2^33! = 7!$ and  $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot 2^44! = 9!$. Let's multiply each $a_n$ by $$\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{2^{n-1} (n-1)!}$$ so that each denominator becomes a factorial. Each $a_n$ multiplies out to $$\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-1)!}$$ We know that $$\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{2^nn!}{2n!}$$ when $n\ge1$. So$$\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-1)!}=\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}2^n n!}{\left(2n\right)!}$$

Comment: always enjoy learning and seeing an alternative method of solving a problem, nice work.